# Cursor code gives the error?

Tags: android

When i use the cursor.moveToNext(); in my code then the application Force finishing activity when i am scrolling down the bottom but when i am remove cursor.moveToNext(); it works normally ?

```
class NoteHolder {
private Button b1 = null;
private Button b2 = null;
private Button b3 = null;


NoteHolder(View row) {
    b1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.one);
    b2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.two);
    b3 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.three);

}

void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {
    b1.setText(helper.getNote(c));
        c.moveToNext();
    b2.setText(helper.getNote(c));
    c.moveToNext();
    b3.setText(helper.getNote(c));
}
```

}

Errors are

```
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 requested, with a size of 16
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at com.example.buttontest.ButtonTest$NoteHelper.getNote(ButtonTest.java:141)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at com.example.buttontest.ButtonTest$NoteHolder.populateFrom(ButtonTest.java:105)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at com.example.buttontest.ButtonTest$NoteAdapter.bindView(ButtonTest.java:71)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2485)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(622):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: My database have 12 values i use the table layout with list view but in the second row its again started to show second value from the database and show me the alert  Force finishing activity when i am reaching down the bottom on scrolling....

Comment: Can't get you exactly can you be more specific about your problem...

Comment: i have three buttons in table layout and my db has 12 values i want to set the text on buttons from database 1->this code gives first three values in first row and in second row it start to set the text on button with second value of the first row and so on.... 2->when i am using moveToNext(); with my code and when i am move to view bottom row it will show Force finishing activity and when i am not using moveToNext(); then scrolling will be ok

Comment: what error you are getting...

Comment: Force finishing activity and my application exited

Comment: It would be better if you see some examples available on net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get a Cursor returned from the database you should do an moveToFirst(); before trying to get data from it. try this

```
void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {
    if (!c.moveToFirst()) return; //if no data dont do anything
    b1.setText(helper.getNote(c));
        c.moveToNext();
    b2.setText(helper.getNote(c));
    c.moveToNext();
    b3.setText(helper.getNote(c));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your ans solved my scrolling problem. But my database have 12 values from this the i want to set the text on the button and with your ans all the rows shows the top three values of the database as the button text.

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean.. you wnat to set 12 text on 12 buttons?

Comment: Yes i want to set 12 text on 12 buttons

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the exception is being raised inside `getNote`, not in `populateForm`.

You should be checking the return code of [`moveToNext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#moveToNext%28%29). If you're already past the end of the result set (i.e. there is no `next`), it will return `false`. In that case, you cannot access row data from that cursor (it effectively points nowhere). So you should not be calling `getNote` on that cursor since it's trying to retrieve data from it.